# Using Juno/LT to run Julia Code, Error, `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::DataFrame, ::ASCIIString

Tags: julia

Below is the first portion of the code I am using. The intention of this code is to, when given a file of images in .bmp format to correctly identity the letter shown in the image.

```
#Install required packages
Pkg.add("Images")
Pkg.add("DataFrames")
using Images
using DataFrames


#typeData could be either "train" or "test.
#labelsInfo should contain the IDs of each image to be read
#The images in the trainResized and testResized data files
#are 20x20 pixels, so imageSize is set to 400.
#path should be set to the location of the data files.

function read_data(typeData, labelsInfo, imageSize, path)

#Intialize x matrix
 x = zeros(size(labelsInfo, 1), imageSize)

for (index, idImage) in enumerate(labelsInfoTrain["ID"])
  #Read image file
  nameFile = "$(path)/$(typeData)Resized/$(idImage).Bmp"
  img = imread(nameFile)
  #Convert img to float values
  temp = float32sc(img)
  #Convert color images to gray images
  #by taking the average of the color scales.
  if ndims(temp) == 3
   temp = mean(temp.data, 1)
  end
  #Transform image matrix to a vector and store
  #it in data matrix
  x[index, :] = reshape(temp, 1, imageSize)
 end
 return x
end
imageSize = 400 # 20 x 20 pixels

#Set location of data files , folders
#Probably will need to set this path to which folder your files are in
path = "C:\\Users\\Aaron\\Downloads\\Math512Project"

#Read information about test data ( IDs )
labelsInfoTest = readtable("$(path)/sampleSubmissionJulia.csv")

#Read test matrixnformation about training data , IDs.
labelsInfoTrain = readtable("$(path)/trainLabels.csv")

#Read training matrix

xTrain = read_data("train", labelsInfoTrain, imageSize, path)
```

the error that I am facing is when the my program reaches the very last line of code above that reads:

```
xTrain = read_data("train", labelsInfoTrain, imageSize, path)
```

I receive an error saying: `getindex` has no method matching getindex(::DataFrame, ::ASCIIString in read_data at benchmarkJeff.jl:18

which refers to the line of code :

```
for (index, idImage) in enumerate(labelsInfoTrain["ID"])
```

Some research online has given me insight that the problem has to do with a conflict when using the DataFrames package and Image package. I was recommended to change the "ID" in my code to [:ID], but this does not solve the problem but rather causes another error. I was wondering if anyone new how to fix this problem or what exactly the problem is with my code. I get the same error when running the code in Julia command line 0.4.0. Look forward to hearing from you.

Comment: Cause of the above error is the one you already mentioned, first replace ["ID"] with correct index that can probably be [:ID], make sure that this column exists `names(labelsInfoTrain)` check type `typeof(labelsInfoTrain)` and its size `size(labelsInfoTrain)`